# How to copy Activesheet from all xlsx files located in a folder to a single workbook excluding a specified file

Tags: vba, excel, loops

**What I Have**
I have the following excel vba programme which copies all the xlsx files from a folder to a single workbook.

**What I Need**
I will be running this from the up.xlsx file located in the same folder discussed above. Therefore i need to modify the code to tell the programme not to open up.xlsx. In other words it should open all xlsx file other than up.xlsx located in the folder and copy them to the up.xlsx

```
 Sub CombineFiles()

Dim Path            As String
Dim FileName        As String
Dim Wkb             As Workbook
Dim WS              As Worksheet

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path 'Change as needed
    FileName = Dir(Path & "\*.xlsx", vbNormal)
    Do Until FileName = ""
        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & "\" & FileName)

        ActiveSheet.Name = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 5)

        ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Workbooks("Up.xlsx").Sheets(Workbooks("Up.xlsx").Sheets.Count)

        Wkb.Close False
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Couldn't you just put `If Filename<>"up.xlsx" Then ... EndIf` inside your loop? Shouldn't it be up.xlsm anyways?

Comment: Hi @arcadeprecinct, Tried it didn't work. Added if statement before open workbook. I will be running his from excel personal workbook so i guess it should not be xlsm

Comment: could you specify what doesm't work? Does it still try to open up.xlsx? Put everything from `Set Wkb...` until `Wkb.Close False` inside the `If ... Then ... End If`

Comment: @arcadeprecinct with your help i got it working. i have put `end if` after `FileName = Dir()` i moved it above and now its working! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You want to merge all data from all workbooks in a folder?  Please see the link below.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win008.htm